# Why isn't the BXEQ instruction in the ARM documentation?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am currently trying to learn assembly, so apologies if this is really rudimentary.

I have cross-compiled a C program using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv8-a`, and then disassembled it with `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d`.
In the disassembled instructions, I see a number of references to the `BXEQ` instruction, e.g.:

```
   1032c:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
   10330:   e7932002    ldr r2, [r3, r2]
   10334:   e3520000    cmp r2, #0
   10338:   012fff1e    bxeq    lr
```

However, I don't see `BXEQ` in any of the ARM documentation.
All I can find is its use in some code examples, but without any explanation or even mention of it: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0607/hpz1474359444075

Please note that I am not asking what `BXEQ` does - I am asking why it is not in the documentation like other ARM instructions.

Comment: `BXEQ` is a `BX{cond}` with an `EQ` condition. You'll find it documented under `BX`.

Comment: If you knew what `BXEQ` did, you'd likely know why it didn't have its own entry in the documentation >.<  I guess not a bad thing to try to keep the question narrow in case how it works hadn't been basically the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes If I knew what `BXEQ` did, I wouldn't have needed to check the documentation in the first place :P

Comment: I was just commenting on the odd "*Please note that I am not asking what BXEQ does*, etc" statement, and the fact that it's not really answerable.  Usually when people say they aren't asking something, that implies they (think) they know what it does, although I assumed that wasn't the implication here.  Anyway, sorry for the noise, the attempt to make the question specific in that way just amused me somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a start, the document you link to is the compiler guide, not really anything to do with the underlying assembler instructions.

What you're looking for is the [instruction set documentation for the `BX` instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0597/2021-12/Base-Instructions/BX--Branch-and-Exchange-), which can use a condition flag to decide whether to do its work.

Perhaps a better (though not necessarily official) document can be found in [this PDF link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwigjvvCm7r1AhU84XMBHRLLDD4QFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fiitd-plos.github.io%2Fcol718%2Fref%2Farm-instructionset.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1mI2Twy2384FcJxVtK3dpj) under section `4.3`:

```
BX - branch and exchange.

  BX{cond} Rn
    {cond} Two character condition mnemonic.
           See Table 4-2: Condition code summary on page 4-5.
    Rn is an expression evaluating to a valid register number.
```

---

This is actually fairly fundamental to the ARM way of doing things, as indicated [here](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/base-isas/a32):

> Most A32 instructions only execute when previous instructions have set a particular condition code. This means that instructions only have their normal effect on the programmers’ model operation, memory and coprocessors if the N, Z, C and V flags satisfy a condition specified in the instruction.

> If the flags do not satisfy this condition, the instruction acts as a NOP. This means that execution advances to the next instruction as normal, including any relevant checks for exceptions being taken, but has no other effect.

> This conditional execution of instructions allows small sections of if- and while-statements to be encoded without the use of branch instructions.